# get match result from array mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

please help me this case.

I have a document:

Example:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "rules": [
    {
      "trigger": {
        "criteria": [
          {
            "type": "A"
          }
        ]
      },
      "benefit": "iphone"
    },
    {
      "trigger": {
        "criteria": [
          {
            "type": "A"
          }
        ]
      },
      "benefit": "ipad"
    },
    {
      "trigger": {
        "criteria": [
          {
            "type": "B"
          }
        ]
      },
      "benefit": "ipad"
    }
  ]
}
```

My expected result is to get benefit iphone and ipad from this document.

```
[
  {
    "benefit": "iphone"
  },
  {
    "benefit": "ipad"
  }
]
```

So I have tried this query:

```
db.collection.find({"id":"1"},{"rules":{"$elemMatch":{"trigger.criteria.type":"A"}}}})
```

I know that $elementMatch just return first match, so changed to aggregate refer to this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {'id': '1'}},
    {$project: {
        rules: {$filter: {
            input: '$rules',
            as: 'rule',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$rule.trigger.criteria.type', 'A']}
        }},
        _id: 0
    }}
])
```

I just receive this.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "rules" : [ ] }
```

Please correct me for this query.
Thanks a lot

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$unwind` pipeline followed by `$match`.finally use `$project` to project the desired field only.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {'_id': '1'}},
   {
       $unwind: "$rules"
   },
    {
       $unwind: "$rules.trigger.criteria"
   },
   {
       $match: {"rules.trigger.criteria.type":"A"}
   },
   {
       $project: 
       {
          "benefit": "$rules.benefit",
           _id:0
       }
   }

])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So for the array, we have to unwind it to access the element inside, right?

Comment: No, we can access the element directly also but $unwind will flatten the array.